# Grouping of favorite tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to add "favorite tag groups" to highlight them in different color?

It will very useful for me:

Example:

- tags group **A** is most interesting for me
- tags group **B** is less interesting, but more intresting that all other(non groupped tags) tags

So, I can

- If there are a lot questions with tags from group **A**, I read them and anything else, group **B** don't distract me. My eyes skip it automatically
- If there are few question with tags from group **A** (or even no such question), I will able to see interesting for me questions anyway

Comment: *> I will able to see most important|interesting questions for me, and skip intresting, but less than first one, but read 2nd group when no new messages in first one.* -- I don't understand what you mean by that. Why do you want to skip "interesting", what is "less than first one"? Where are "messages" involved in all of this? What defines whether something is "important" or "interesting"? Can you [edit] your question to be a bit more specific -- maybe including an example?

Comment: @slhck. Hope it'smore clear now

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I find the existing Favorite / Ignored system quite powerful already. From my point of view, group **A** is *most interesting* (favorite), group **0** is *not interested* (ignored) and group **B**, *less interesting*, is everything else (allows me to learn something new on SO *every single day*).

That said, as a feature request, your question is, indeed, *interesting*. However, in my humble opinion, it's much more complex than it looks from a design standpoint. For instance, limiting the feature to two groups is probably not the way to go (*avoid coding for `2`, always aim for `0`, `1` or `N`*), as other users might be pleased with the feature but also want to have, say, additional groups **C** and **D** (or group **-1** for *more ignored* tags). The whole thing would then proceed to end up being a giant mess.

Even when limiting the feature to two groups, there are still conflicting decisions the algorithm has to make. Let's say you like tags [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) and [quux](/questions/tagged/quux) *very much*, they're in group **A**. You also like tags [bar](/questions/tagged/bar) and [fred](/questions/tagged/fred), but *not as much*, so the poor things have been demoted to group **B**. Then somebody asks this question:

> #### How can I bar the foo of my quux?
>
> I have a quux, and its foo has to be barred for my code to work. What should I do?
>
> [foo](/questions/tagged/foo)<sub>**(A)**</sub> [bar](/questions/tagged/bar)<sub>**(B)**</sub> [quux](/questions/tagged/quux)<sub>**(A)**</sub>

Which group wins?

1. Question belongs to **A**, because *most interesting* trumps *less interesting*.
2. Question belongs to **B**, because *less interesting* trumps *most interesting*.
3. Question belongs to **A**, because *most interesting* outnumbers *less interesting*.

Now we have a problem. The answer to the question above is very subjective and will depend on the user. Technically, we would have to support the three of them. Of course, we can decide to only implement `3` because it's more fair or something, but then the questioner would realize he didn't specify the language he's using and would update his question:

> #### How can I bar the foo of my quux, using fred?
>
> I have a quux, and its foo has to be barred for my code to work. I'm using fred. What should I do?
>
> [foo](/questions/tagged/foo)<sub>**(A)**</sub> [bar](/questions/tagged/bar)<sub>**(B)**</sub> [quux](/questions/tagged/quux)<sub>**(A)**</sub> [fred](/questions/tagged/fred)<sub>**(B)**</sub>

So we still have the same problem. How do we deal with tags from multiple groups?

1. Question belongs to **A**, because *most interesting* trumps *less interesting*.
2. Question belongs to **B**, because *less interesting* trumps *most interesting*.
3. Question belongs to a mix of **A** and **B**, and its background color should be set to the *intermediate value* between the colors defined for **A** and **B**.
4. Question belongs to a mix of **A** and **B**, and its background color should be set to the *weighted value* computed from the colors defined for **A** and **B** and their respective rate against other tag groups on that post.
5. Favorite tag groups should have a priority, *higher* priorities trump *lower* priorities.
6. Favorite tag groups should have a priority, *lower* priorities trump *higher* priorities.
7. Favorite tag groups should have a list of tag groups that have less priority than this tag group.
8. And maybe also a list a tag groups that have higher priority, for good measure.
9. Nobody will be satisfied with that feature anyway.